# Integrate a function over a contour including infinitely many poles, such as $\int_{|z|=1}1/\sin(1/z)\,dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

We can find complex integration of a function over a closed contour by residue theorem if there are only finite many singularity inside the contour. But my question is how to find  the integration if there are infinite many singularity inside the contour? Please help me solve this type of problem mention below.
$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{\sin(\frac{1}{z})} dz$$

Comment: It may be helpful that this is $\int_0^{2\pi} dz / \sin(\sin\phi - i\cos\phi)$. You might find an antiderivative featuring a Bessel function But that seems very nasty and any residue approach should be preferred.

Comment: is there no short and direct method?

Comment: I don't know, I am not an authority on this topic. Just gave my two cents.

Comment: I think that the problem here is that $\sin(1/z)$ is not a meromorphic function, so no residue theory can be applied.

Comment: ok then only general method of integration is remaining?

Comment: perhaps a new variable u=1/z. we have $dz=-\frac{du}{u^2}$, the contour is |u|=1 and the integral is more fun. $\int_{|u|=1} -\frac{du}{u^2\sin(u)}.$

Comment: u could use the residue at infinity, so instead of looking at the inside of the unit circle u look at it's exterior. By Cauchy they are the same

Comment: @ claudeh5 now it becomes very simple...

Comment: @Claudeh5 is it ok to replace 1/z by u?

Comment: the result is $i \pi/3 $ if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: @tired please give your calculation if possible...

Comment: @neela done, hope it helps

Comment: yes thanks a lot ....i am looking at the solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok this is what i would do (i assume the unit circle is traversed in counter clockwise direction):

Let's denote
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{\sin(1/z)}
$$
As the OP already noted the integrand behaves quite nasty inside the unit disc. The reason is the infinite number of poles showing up as $z\rightarrow 0$.
So what can we do?

One idea would be to look at the outside of the unit disc rather then into its inside because we only have one pole at $z=\infty$rather then an uncountable number which is not so bad.

By residue theorem, the countour integral around the pole at infinity is the negative of the integral around the unit circle. We get
$$
\oint_{|z|=1}f(z)dz=-2\pi i\text{Res}(f(z),z=\infty)
$$

the residue at infinity is given by
$$
\text{Res}(f(z),z=\infty)=\text{Res}(-f(\frac{1}{z})/z^2,z=0)
$$

using $\sin(z)=z-z^3/3!+z^5/5!+\mathcal{O}(z^7)$ and expand the fraction as a geometric series we get $\text{Res}(f(z),z=\infty)=-1/6$ and

$$
\oint_{|z|=1}f(z)dz=\frac{\pi i}{3}
$$

as announced in the comments

Comment: thanking you for your precise time...

Comment: Minor comment: The third and fourth summands of the Taylor expansion should be $z^5/5! + \mathcal{O}(z^7)$.

Comment: @GDumphart, thanks i corrected it

Answer (score 1):

$I=\oint_{|z|=1}f(z)dz=-\oint_{|u|=1}\frac{du}{u^2 \sin(u)}=\frac{\pi i}{3}$

(the rotation is not in the trigonometric sense, as the residus inside $|z|=1$ are outside |u=1| with $z=1/u$).

The residue of $\frac1{u^2 \sin(u)}$ in $u=0$ is $\frac16$. This is linked to the theory of residue at infinity.