# Residue of $\sec(1/z)$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

It's been a while since I last did some complex analysis calculations, so I need your help. I'm required to  calculate the residue of $\sec(1/z)$ at $z=0$. Let me say first that I've tried to search here how to do it, but I didn't find anything useful (sorry if my searching skills weren't good enough).

So $z=0$ is neither a pole nor a removable singularity of $\sec(1/z)$, which makes the calculations a bit hard. I have no idea how to compute its Laurent series near $z=0$. I thought maybe Taylor would help, but the radius of convergence is $\pi/2$ (if my calculations weren't wrong). I used to know what to do at these problematic cases but I totally forgot.

Thanks!

Comment: Any function even function which has a residue at $0$ has $0$ at the residue. But, as the answer below says, this function doesn’t have a residue.

Answer (score 3):

It makes no sense to talk about the residue of $\sec\left(\frac1z\right)$ at $0$. That concept is only defined for *isolated* singularities, and $0$ is not one such singularity, since $\sec\left(\frac1z\right)$ has singularities arbitrarily close to $0$; just consider the numbers of the form $\left(\frac\pi2+k\pi\right)^{-1}$, with $k\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Why does the singularity have to be isolated?

Comment: Because otherwise there is no Laurent series centered at that singularity. And, by definition, the residue is a certain coefficient of that Laurent series.

Comment: it's an interesting problem, since $1/z$ can be formally substituted into the Taylor series for secant, and you get a perfectly reasonable looking series that turns out not to converge anywhere

Comment: In that case, how would you calculate the integral $\oint\sec(1/z)\ \mathrm{d}z$ over $|z|=R$ when $R\to 0$? I mean, what if I want to use the Residue Theorem here? I just can't? Or do I not consider the singularity and the integral is just $0$?

Comment: You cannot apply the residue theorem in that situation. And, no, you cannot consider that the integral is just $0$. Use [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1553073/446262) instead.